# events not firing in VisualForce

Tags: ajax, salesforce, visualforce

In the page below,Topic__c is a single-select picklist. My intention is to have this list control which of the input fields is available below. The user selects an option, and the onchange event should fire, and rerender the fields.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Topic__c}" id="topic" > 
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="tickerInput,sectorInput,bondInput">  
             <apex:param name="topicSelection" value="{!Call_Report__c.Topic__c}" /> 
            </apex:actionSupport> 
 </apex:inputField>
<apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Tickers__c}" rendered="{!Call_Report__c.Topic__c='Issuer'}" id="tickerInput" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Sector__c}" rendered="{!Call_Report__c.Topic__c='Industry'}" id="sectorInput"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Security__c}" rendered="{!Call_Report__c.Topic__c='Specific Bond'}" id="bondInput" />
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here? http://community.salesforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Multi-select-picklist-not-firing-event-for-AJAX-refreshes/m-p/173572/highlight/false#M22119 seems to imply that what I am doing is reasonable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to rerender at a higher level than that, like at the level of an `<apex:outputPanel id="thePanel"> or an <apex:page id="thePage">`

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Try wrapping your code in an outputPanel and rerendering that.